# Assignning value with for loop in two dimensional arrays (matrixes in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

My code is this. I want to add random numbers between 10-99 range. And when the code is running it gives such a problem. All of the four lines become the same. Also I try to give the numbers with `input` but in this time also the result was the same. Only the first given four integers take all the four lines.

```
import random

mx = [[0]*4] * 4

for i in range(4):

    for j in range(4):
        num = random.randint(10,99)
        mx[i][j] = num

#printing
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        print(mx[i][j],sep=" ",end=" ")
    print()
```

And it gives this problem

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop>python file.py
89 98 99 67
89 98 99 67
89 98 99 67
89 98 99 67
```

**What is problem in the source code?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `mx = [[0]*4] * 4` you are **not** creating a list of lists with zeros. You are instead creating a list with references to the same list. Any change made to one of the lists will make a change to all of them.

Take a look at the related questions:
1. [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)
2. [How can I make multiple empty lists in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520876/how-can-i-make-multiple-empty-lists-in-python)
3. [How to create a list or tuple of empty lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880037/how-to-create-a-list-or-tuple-of-empty-lists-in-python)

For 2D lists, there really isn't a 'clean' way of doing it. I would suggest using [numpy.zeros](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) or go with

```py
 mx = [[0, 0, 0, 0], \
       [0, 0, 0, 0], \
       [0, 0, 0, 0], \
       [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the goal to just give you the 4x4 array, or also the presentation?
The array could be achieved in a list comprehension like this:

`[print([random.randint(10,99) for x in range(4)]) for y in range(4)]`

Output:

```
[15, 57, 37, 90]
[40, 58, 39, 67]
[97, 38, 84, 86]
[14, 72, 50, 13]
```

Comment: If you wanted to get rid of the brackets and commas, you could unpack with an asterix in your print() like so:
```[print(*[random.randint(10,99) for x in range(4)]) for y in range(4)]```

Answer (score 0):

`mx = [[0]*4] * 4` will only reproduce the same list 4 times. It will not create 4 individual lists like you intend to. You could try something like in the code below, to create individual lists inside a list.

```
mx = [None] * 4

for i in range(4):
    mx[i] = [None] * 4
    for j in range(5):
        num = random.randint(10,99)
        mx[i][j] = num
```